# How to refer a eval reference in rex to change the group name dynamically in splunk

Tags: splunk

How to use eval reference in rex command.

Here is what I have tried so far:

**MyMacro**: myrextest(1)

```
| eval test= "Hello"
| eval myinput = $myinput$
| eval rexString = "'$myinput$':'(?<$myinput$>[^*']+)"
| rex field=payload "'$myinput$':'(?<$myinput$>[^*']+)"
```

**Search String without eval and it is working fine :**

```
    | eval payload = "{'description':'snapshot created from 
       test','snapShotName':'instance1-disk-2-cio- 
        1564744963','sourceDisk':'instance1-disk-2','status':'READY'}"
     `myrextest("snapShotName")`
```

output from search string:

```
        rexString:  'snapShotName':'(?<snapShotName>[^*']+)
```

**Search String with eval:**

```
   | makeresults 
   | eval payload = "{'description':'snapshot created from 
     test','snapShotName':'instance1-disk-2-cio-1564744963','sourceDisk':'instance1- 
     disk-2','status':'READY'}"
   | eval myMacroInput = "snapShotName"
   `myrextest(myMacroInput)`
```

**output from search string:**

```
'myMacroInput':'(?<myMacroInput>[^*']+)
```

Based on my observation when I am passing eval reference to my macro and using it in rex it is not replacing the value it is replacing with eval reference.

Can some one please help me on it, I have tired a lot but unfortunately I didn't get any solution .

Answer (score 1):

After changing my input parameter format, I am able to achieve it

```
| makeresults
| eval payload = "{'description':'snapshot created from ciolake','snapShotName':'instance1-disk-2-cio-1564744963','sourceDisk':'instance1-disk-2','status':'READY'}"
| foreach snapShotName description sourceDisk
 [eval <<FIELD>> = "<<FIELD>>" | rex field=payload "'
 <<FIELD>>':'(?<rexgroupnam>[^*']+)"
 | rename rexgroupnam as "<<FIELD>>" ]
```

Comment: Nicely done!  I've saved this.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments to macros are taken literally, even if the argument is a field name.  To show this, try

```
| makeresults 
| eval payload = "{'description':'snapshot created from 
       test','snapShotName':'instance1-disk-2-cio- 
        1564744963','sourceDisk':'instance1-disk-2','status':'READY'}" 
| `myrextest(snapShotName)`
```

and you should get the same results as from

```
| makeresults 
| eval payload = "{'description':'snapshot created from 
       test','snapShotName':'instance1-disk-2-cio- 
        1564744963','sourceDisk':'instance1-disk-2','status':'READY'}" 
| `myrextest("snapShotName")`
```

I don't care for this behavior.  If you don't either, then consider filing an enhancement request at https://ideas.splunk.com

Comment: you are right the above conditions will work, but my usecase is different, I will get the comma separated keys, I have to loop through those keys and get the value from log using rex command. in that case the argument value will by dynamical right.

Comment: Example: foreach key***[ `myrextest(<<FILED>>)`]